# While loop assignment in C don't work as expected

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, while-loop

Trying to print all names read from a file ordered alphabetically.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int compare(const void *a, const void *b){
    const char **ia = (const char **)a;
    const char **ib = (const char **)b;
    return strcmp(*ia, *ib);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    //Takes input in terminal/cmd (filename.txt).
    char *input = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
    if (argc < 2){
        printf("Enter filename: ");
        scanf("%s", input);
    } else
        input = argv[1];
    //.......................


    int count = 0; //Names count
    char *names[100]; //Pointers to each name in file
    char str[50];
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(input, "r");

    //Allocate space for the pointers
    for (int i = 0; i < 100;i++){
        names[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (50 + 1));
    }

    //Adding names to array
    if (file) {
        while ((fgets(str, 50, file)) != NULL){
            count++;
            names[count] = str;
            printf("%s", names[count]); //This will print names as read from file
        }      
        fclose(file);
        printf("%s", names[2]); //This will print the last name read with the while loop no matter the index of names[]

    } else printf("Can't read from file");

    //Sorting "names" in alphabetical order
    int length = sizeof(names)/sizeof(char*); //length of names
    qsort(names, length, sizeof(char*), compare);

    //printing each name (will be the last string read by while loop times the length)
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        printf("%s", names[i]);

    }
    printf("%d", count); //printing names count
}
```

Compiling and running the program gives me this output:

```
Tredigar
Ghorvas
Wolvar
Lurtrum
Sabakzar
Hagan
Korlag
Malagar
Ferrek
Baelnar
Grimmalk
Roken
Vabul
Radek
Agaro
Krag
Balfam
Vistrum
Halzar
Maulnar
Auxlan
Krim
Borkul
Thorin
Morak
Arnan
Garmul
Avamir
Darkul
Bariken
Mardam
Hlant
Rogath
Melgar
Thorbalt
Dyrnar
Ezegan
Smethykk
Sharak
Swargar
Halagmar
Rozag
Orobok
Arval
Kurman
Erag
Dolmen
Glint
Haeltar
Haeltar
8┼Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
Haeltar
49
```

Obviously I'm trying to sort the strings in alphabetical order. My current problem is that wherever I print *names[]* outside the while loop the pointers all point to Haeltar which is the last name assigned in the while loop. I've searched far and wide but haven't been able to figure out what's causing this behavior. I am relatively new to C programming.

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger and/or add debug print messages to see what your code is doing. You should read [How to Debug Small Programs](https://www.google.com/amp/s/ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/amp/).

Comment: Don't cast `void *`!

Comment: I've been trying to set up a debugger for C in VS Code for windows. After trying and reading for hours without getting it to work properly I kinda gave up and downloaded the C extension plugin for Visual Studio IDE. I haven't gotten to start programming with C in VS IDE yet. Might as well start now.

Comment: OT: In C there there is need to cast here: `const char **ia = (const char **)a;`

Comment: OT: `count` and length` both should be `size_t` not `int`.

Comment: You will probably want to remove the newlines from the names before you go much further.  `fgets()` includes the newline in what it returns.

Comment: @KevinFrostad, check this code I wrote: http://ideone.com/KVtr67. It's not the best but it seems to do the job, can be improved alot more though.

Comment: I've removed your "fix" from the question - there is no need to add that to your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `names[count] = str;` assigns every member of your array the address of `str`. They all **point** to it. So naturally they all point to `"Haeltar"`, which is what was last written into `str`. Note that in doing the assignment, you also leak all the allocated memory too.

You'll need to either define `names` as `char names[100][50]` and read directly into it `fgets(names[count], 50, file)`. Or allocate memory for each member (using `malloc`, like you already did) and  copy into it (using `strcpy`)<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> If you are lucky enough to be on a POSIX system, `strdup` can do both in a single call.

Comment: The elements of `names` have had memory allocated to.

Comment: Thank you, that does make a lot of sense. It worked perfectly. If I have gotten it right, *strcpy* makes a new variable copied from str at the allocated space which *names[i]* points at, right?

Comment: @KevinFrostad, to word exactly: `strcpy` copies one *null-terminated* `char` buffer into another buffer. So in your case the origin buffer is `str` and the target is pointed to by `names[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

There are several errors:

Firstly you must copy the input string to the array, you only replace the pointer originally from malloc.

```
strcpy(names[count], str);
```

Next, you must increment `count` after you use it, not before: you have left element `0` unused.

Third, you are using `length` in two places where you should be using `count` - the actual number of entries, here

```
qsort(names, count, sizeof(char*), compare);    // change length to count
```

and here

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {                // change length to count
```

Comment: I've corrected it, thanx for noticing. Ultimately changing *names[count] = str;* to *strcpy(names[count], str)* is what fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 obvious bugs:
1) you increase `count` too soon. The first entry in the names array is unassigned and can crash your app since you try to print it.

```
if (file) {
        while ((fgets(str, 50, file)) != NULL){
            names[count] = str;
            printf("%s", names[count]); //This will print names as read from file
            ++count;
        }
```

2) you count the strings but print using `length` instead. change it to `count` and it will work.

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i){
        printf("%s", names[i]);    
}
```

Comment: Very good, but the 3rd bug - and the direct cause of what OP is seeing - is the bad string assignment.